# say it’s not so! -- what does that "say" mean?

Tags: comprehension

Example:

> There are an abundance of books on computer architectures, computer
>   logic, and computer mathematics, and most of these works discuss various
>   techniques for representing and manipulating numbers inside computers.
>   Sadly, however, it appears that the majority of these tomes are
>   written by visitors from the planet Mars, whose keen understanding of
>   higher mathematics is somewhat offset by their limited grasp of the
>   English language.
>   “**Say it’s not so!**” you cry, but the proof is irrefutable. When was the
>   last time you waded through a book on computer mathematics without
>   your brain overheating? Much like reading Being and Nothingness by the
>   famous French philosopher Jean Paul Sartre, one could mull over many
>   of these cryptic masterpieces until the end of time without gaining so
>   much as the faintest clue as to what was in their authors’ minds.

I don't understand what it's trying to say. As far as I know, the word *say*, when used like that, is usually very similar in meaning to the expression *for example* or *let's assume for a moment that*, but it doesn't sound like what we have here is anything remotely along those lines. What do you guys think?

Comment: It means *declare*, *tell me*, *reassure me*. It's a very common phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Say* has its ordinary sense ('declare', 'state', 'speak [a specific utterance]*), and it is cast in the *imperative* mode: a demand or request to perform the action. The speaker requests her addressee to declare that *it* (whatever that may be) is not the case, to deny *it*.

The writer is probably echoing (consciously or unconsciously) a legendary baseball anecdote, which claims that the great left fielder Shoeless Joe Jackson, accused of having conspired with professional gamblers to throw the 1919 World Series, was accosted in the street by a boy who implored him to "Say it ain't so, Joe!"

Answer (score 1):

***“Say it’s not so!”*** is a common phrase, and we can understand it literally.

As StoneyB and Dan Bron suggested, there is nothing special about this *Say*. It seems like the other common expression of *say* as in *"Let's say ..."* (e.g. *"Say you have $200, what will you buy?"*) confuses you. I think it could be helpful if you think of this *Say* as "*Please say (that) ...*".

So, *“Say it’s not so!”* means "Please say that it's not so." In other words, please assure me that it's not so. Please tell me that's not true. I don't want to hear that. I don't want to think that is true! ***I don't want to believe that it is so!***

Let's recap.

> *Say you have $200, what will you buy?* -- an assumption
>   *Say it's not so.* -- a request (for a reassurance)